# Connosco ou Conosco? Qual é a forma correta de se escrever?

Tags: escrita

Recentemente me deparei com esta questão.

Qual a correta forma de se escrever "Connosco" ou "Conosco"?

Answer (score 12):

Depende, em português de Portugal escreve-se **connosco** e em português do Brasil escreve-se **conosco**.

> connosco | pron. pess. 2 g.
>
> con·nos·co |ô| pronome pessoal de dois géneros
>
> 1. Flexão do pronome nós, quando se emprega com a preposição com.
> 2. Em nossa companhia.
> 3. De nós para nós.
> 4. A nosso respeito.
>
> Ver também dúvida linguística: [connosco ou conosco?](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/3972).
>
> • Grafia no Brasil: conosco.
>   Palavras relacionadas: lhe, me, comigo,
>   nos, vós, convosco, nosco .
>
> "connosco", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, https://dicionario.priberam.org/connosco [consultado em
>   03-12-2019].

Comment: mais uma diferença transatlântica que aprendo.